# Not able to change default download directory for chrome with selenium hub docker and ruby watir

Tags: ruby, selenium, docker, watir

After a few days of searching and experimenting with any of the solutions I could find online, I give up and want to get some help from the community.

Ruby gems (ruby 2.5.1):

```
watir 6.11.0
selenium-webdriver 3.4.1
```

Docker:

```
selenium/node-chrome-debug:3.14
selenium/hub:3.14
```

My ruby code:

```
prefs = {
    download: {
        prompt_for_download: false,
        default_directory: download_directory
    }
}
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, url: selenium_hub_url, options: {prefs: prefs})
```

Our set-up is:

1. Run a selenium/hub and a selenium/node-chrome-debug. Something that might be different is that we are mounting the /tmp of the base OS as /hosttmp/tmp in the node container
2. Make the selenium/node-chrome-debug talk to selenium/hub
3. Make the browser automation talk to the selenium/hub using the code provided above

The problem is that I was never able to set the default download directory. However, all other parts are working correctly. The VNC window shows the browser is working correctly despite the default download directory settings. It is always /home/seluser/Downloads

Things I have tried:

1. Other people's ideas such as different ways to specify the options and preferences. (e.g. using the Capabilities)
2. Docker security-related settings such as: --privileged --security-opt apparmor:unconfined --cap-add SYS_ADMIN
3. On the base OS, chmod 777 for the download_directory. The download_directory, for example, /tmp/tmp.123 on the base OS, which is mounted as /hosttmp/tmp/tmp.123 in the chrome node container, I could see it and make a few read/write operations in this folder inside the container or on the base OS
4. Tweaks about the interesting ruby symbol/string stuff when creating a Hash object.

Does anyone have more ideas about what could lead to this situation? What else I could try? And is there any log that I could refer to. There is no error or warning when running the code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, by digging into the source code of the Watir and Selenium-Webdriver, I think I know the 'root cause'.

I have created an issue since I am not sure if this is a bug or a 'feature' [The issue](https://github.com/watir/watir/issues/812)

Also, I have a workaround for my case, in watir/capabilities.rb:

Change

```
@selenium_browser = browser == :remote || options[:url] ? :remote : browser
```

to

```
@selenium_browser = browser == :remote ? :remote : browser
```

This shouldn't be the final solution as it might not be a good idea. Will wait for what the Watir people say about this.

Answer (score 1):

Did you define `options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new`?

We use

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
prefs = {
  prompt_for_download: false,
  default_directory: download_directory
}
options.add_preference(download: prefs)
```

and then you would want something like

`browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, url: selenium_hub_url, options: options)`

But maybe the main problem is just that you are using
`options: {prefs: prefs}`
instead of
`options: {download: prefs}`

Comment: I have tried to use the Option. That's one of the solutions that I have found online, actually. And it just doesn't work, as well..

Comment: That implementation is (which seems to exactly the same as yours..): 
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
download_setting = {
            prompt_for_download: false,
            default_directory: "/hosttmp/#{download_location}"
          }
options.add_preference(download: download_setting)
Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, url: selenium_hub_url, options: options)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Java+Docker+Selenium+Chrome for automation test and also met similar issue with you. Please find my solutions below and try if it works for your case.

1. Don't set default download directory in the options, just leave "/home/seluser/Downloads" as it is.
2. When you start up the chrome node on docker, please add the parameter of volume that could transfer the downloaded files to the directory you want.

e.g. docker run -d -p 5900:5900 --link myhub:hub -v :/home/seluser/Downloads selenium/node-chrome-debug:3.14.0

In my case, the JDK environment and my test script is on Linux machine while the selenium webdriver & browser are all on docker, so once the file downloaded by browser it cannot saved directly on Linux machine, you have to mount the local directory with default directory on docker. Then you could find the file saved in the directory you want. 
Thanks & Regards!
Jing